# How to sum value from database and input value in textbox

Tags: php, mysql

here is my problem: I get the value of STOCK from the database and I input a value in textbox, the problem is that when I try to compute the system does not recognized or say **undefined index: stock**

here is the syntax from value to computation:

```
<td><input type = "text" name = "stock[]"  size = "5" value = '<?php echo $row['stock'];  ?>' disabled></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'stockin[]' size = '5'></td>
<td><input type  ="submit" name = "btn" value = "re-stock"></td>
```

here is the syntax for computation which I place after the  tag

```
<?php
$capture_field_vals1="";
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    foreach($_POST['stockin'] as $key => $text_field){
        $capture_field_vals1 .= $text_field;
    }
    echo $capture_field_vals1;

$num1 = $_POST['stock[]'];
$num2 = $_POST['$capture_field_vals1'];
$num3 = $num1 + $num2;
echo $num3;
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here: `$num2 = $_POST['$capture_field_vals1'];` ?

Comment: i want to add the value that I input on the stockin, I try to declare that If it may work... but the end it wasn't

Comment: do you somehow use javascript to add more then one value ? if no then change `<input name="stock[]">` to `<input name="stock">` and in PHP `$_POST['stock']` is value from form...

Comment: You could use a sprinkling of JavaScript to add the values

Answer (score 0):

"[]" means array, at this point you might need to write more than one data to the database. Also in the PHP script, you could observe incoming post by `var_dump($_POST);`

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST["stock"]) ){
    foreach ($_POST["stock"] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value."<BR>";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="?">
<input type = "text" name = "stock[]"  size = "5" value = '1'/>
<input type = "text" name = "stock[]"  size = "5" value = '2'/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how will i add the display value and the input value? thats my question which I try solve and it is not working

Comment: I had just changed the previous post a little bit.